# sql convert row with line separated string to individual rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
id, names, group
1, 'mike\nsteve', 1
2, 'maria\npeter\nlisa', 1
```

the names are saved as a string with line feeds.
I want to move all names to separate rows in another table:

```
id, name, group
1, mike, 1
2, steve, 1
3, maria, 1
4, peter, 1
5, lisa, 1
```

Can I do this in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is `union all`

```
select id, substring_index(names, '\n', 1), group
from t
union all
select id, substring_index(substring_index(names, '\n', 2), '\n', -1), group
from t
where names like '%\n%'
union all
select id, substring_index(substring_index(names, '\n', 3), '\n', -1), group
from t
where names like '%\n%\n%'
. . .
```

You will need to add more subqueries up to the maximum number of names in the string.

You can use `create table as` or `insert into . . .` to put these in another table.

Comment: The OP wants to insert those then into another table.